# Android application with a webview in Main Activity and Fragment[activity2: HeaderActivity]

Tags: android, webview, fragment

I want to display MainActivity having webview(webview is already in MainActivity) and a fragment say Activity2. here's is the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="chronical.com.sayc.HeaderFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/activity_header_fragment" />

<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that it is not displaying the HeaderActivity. When the app starts, it is displaying only the webview.

Comment: your webview filling parent that's why fragment is not showing...

Comment: give some margin from top to `webView` and set its height `wrap_content`

Comment: @Rohit Even after changing webview to wrap_content, the problem is still there

Comment: @Anshul, Still nothing. Only webview is displayed.

Comment: share you r code along with fragment

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="chronic.com.sayc.HeaderFragment"
android:background="#ffcaff3f">
</RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 0):

your webview height is  match_parent

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
```

please change height of webview

and set the linear layout orientation

android:orientation="vertical"

Comment: still..the same problem

Comment: by default listview orientation is horizontal change it to vertical

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="chronical.com.sayc.HeaderFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_header_fragment" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.8" />

</LinearLayout>

You can use the **android:layout_weight** property to divide your parent view depending on the weight of its child view like for example 20% of your parent view will be covered by fragment and 80% by the WebView.
```

Comment: Tried the same thing...still it's not showing the fragment Activity

Comment: then you have some other issue i guess because i tested it on my machine and its working fine.